# Detect object speed?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have some objects that I need to know how fast they are going. I have a property, "speed," and I would like it to show the object's speed in blender units. For the unit, it doesn't matter that much as long as I can read it. Python or logic would work, but if it's a script I'll have it **running at all times.** In other words, I'll be using this every logic tic so it needs to be efficient. Thanks.

**EDIT: I've figured out how to find velocity on my own, but how would I use that xyz info to find speed?**

Comment: every second or every logic tick?

Comment: I want the property to display speed every tick.

Comment: speed or velocity, not a physicist but I think their slightly different.

Comment: @Vince Scalia Probably velocity, although I don't see a difference.

Comment: Does this solve it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29007/a-way-to-get-rate-of-change-in-translation-or-rotation-into-a-shader-node/29184#29184 ? You can call it with scene_update handler instead of frame_change

Comment: @VinceScalia velocity is the whole vector, speed is just the scalar..

Comment: Oh... thought it was the other way. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a nice script from [here](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/GameModule/ClassKX_GameObject_14.html), and it is the following:

```
# get the controller
controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()

# get the game object that the controller is attached to.
obj = controller.owner

# get local (game object) linear velocity
linVelocity = obj.getLinearVelocity(True)
```

I have modified it for my own scene, and I've also defined speed.

Answer (score 5):

Keep track of the objects previous position. Algorithm:

```
on each logic tick:
     speed_vector = current_position - previous_position
     speed = speed_vector.length()
     previous_position = current_position
```