# There is no object info node in Animation Nodes addon

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

I use blender 2.76 official build for Linux, with 1.0.1 Animation Nodes addon, and I don not have object info node to get object velocity. According to this tutorial it does exists:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52nKM35LRZM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Velocity sockets have been removed, related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42078/how-can-i-know-the-speed-of-an-object-inside-a-loop

Comment: The node is called "Object Transforms Input" now. And @poor is right that the velocity sockets have been removed. :)

Comment: @JacquesLucke Just out of interest: Any plans on re-implementing this feature?

Comment: hm no, I don't think so. Problem is that it doesn't work in all cases (only if there are fcurves and there is no parent object, etc..) And when you really need it you can combine it with existing nodes. If you are clever you put it into a subprogram, so that it is reuseable.

Comment: Thank you poor and @JacquesLucke, that way it works. If somebody convert it to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I originally called the node "Object Info" because I had no idea how large the whole addon will become. At some point I noticed that I will need multiple nodes that get data from objects and to avoid some confusion I decided to rename some nodes to give them more detailed and exact names.

This is why the "Object Info" node is called "**Object Transforms Input**" nowadays. Beside that there are *Object Attribute/Matrix/... Input* nodes.

The *Velocity* sockets have been removed because they did not fit in very well, they made the code more complicated and (most importantly) did not work in all cases.

If you still want to know the velocity of an object you can get it with a little workaround (this does exactly what the node internally did before):

[image]