# How to integrate vehicle speed into wheel rotations?

Tags: animation

I'm animating the rotation of wheels on a vehicle, and I'm planning to match the vehicle's behaviour to a table of MPH (miles per hour) that's sampled every second. This MPH data comes from a captured logfile from a real vehicle's progress on the road.

I'm not translating the vehicle in world space - just rotating the wheels.

I can easily enough create, say, an empty object with an MPH parameter which I can animate in the timeline. Is there an easy way to adjust the wheels' rotation rate to match? Currently, my wheels are rotated by animating the rotation angle, so angle of rotation will be an integration over time of MPH somehow.

Is there an easy way to do this in Blender? And built-in integrate-with-respect-to-time functions? Or a way to animate by rotation rate rather than angle?

Comment: You might want to look into *Drivers*: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with drivers, but I'm not sure how to do the integration with respect to time, or if there's a way to animate the rate of rotation instead of the angle.

Comment: Then maybe an app.handler could help you to get the rate of change, similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29184/7777. But I suppose you could get the rate of change from your data, couldn't you? And animate that directly.

Comment: In the end, I've used a spreadsheet to apply an approximation using the trapezoidal rule. I know, it's a cop-out, but it gives me the data I need.