# How to calculate a difference between current and previous location vectors using animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

In my node tree I have a location vector that is streamed from a sensor, how would I calculate a difference between current and previous location vectors using animation nodes?

Comment: The velocity? How is this location vector defined? Parametric equation, Fcurves, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animation Nodes and Velocity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110084/animation-nodes-and-velocity)

Comment: @OmarAhmad I don't have Fcurves, the vector is a realtime data that is coming outside of blender.

Comment: So you are parsing some file containing the location vectors and you want to compute the difference between vectors across frames? Can you share some more information about your setup?

Comment: @OmarAhmad No, the vector data is streamed from a sensor

Comment: I see. Will write an answer now. Can you add this information to your original question by editing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on my [other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105090/how-to-store-particle-locations-in-a-list/105178#105178) about passing data between executions in Animation Nodes.

We store the vector list received from the sensor in memory by storing it in an attribute in the `AN` python module using this command:

```
AN.sensorLocations = sensorLocations
```

At the next execution, if we get the data at `AN.sensorLocations` it will be that of the last execution. And thus, if we subtract it from the data received from the sensor we will get the information we want. So, the node tree is as follows.

[image: Node Tree]

Where the output of the subtract node is the output we require. To avoid any confusion due to order of execution of nodes, we use the output of the subtract node as a dummy variable (A non used variable) `_` in the expression node that stores the data. This ensures the subtract node executes before the expression node.

The initial execution will face an error due to the fact that there is no data in `AN.sensorLocations`, but this error disappear at later executions which is fine in our case because the sensor provide an up-to-date information about the location.

Comment: You can also use the [reassign parameter](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/loop.html) feature in the loop, which behaves the same way.

Comment: @zippy We are talking about moving data across executions, not in the same one. Loops are useless in that regard.

Comment: @OmarAhmad I misunderstood.  When OP wrote "vector data is streamed from a sensor" I thought AN would be running/looping to respond to live data.